# Get data from Mysql database with fastest query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table like that.

[image]

I want to get "cost" base on date and time with fastest query.

For example:

Input:

```
id_room = 1;
date = 2017/03/24
time from: 05:30:00
time end: 07:30:00
```

The column "cost" means cost per hour.

How to get amount of cost from timeFrom to timeEnd ?

Comment: Cost is what, the price per hour?

Answer (score 1):

in short:

```
SELECT SUM((time_to_sec(timediff(LEAST('07:30:00', timeTo), GREATEST('05:30:00', timeFrom))) / 3600) * cost)
FROM `roomcost` r
WHERE WEEKDAY('2017-03-23') BETWEEN dayFrom AND dayTo 
AND (timeFrom <= '05:30:00' OR timeTo >= '07:30:00')
AND id_room = 1
```

my test data:

```
INSERT INTO `roomcost` (`id`, `id_room`, `dayFrom`, `dayTo`, `timeFrom`, `timeTo`, `cost`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 6, '05:00:00', '06:00:00', '50.00'),
(2, 1, 1, 6, '06:00:00', '17:00:00', '100.00'),
(3, 1, 0, 0, '05:00:00', '10:00:00', '200.00');
```

explanation:

1. select all valid rows from your roomcost table. `WEEKDAY` gives you date weekday part of a given date
2. with `GREATEST` and `LEAST` you get the intersecting time ranges.
3. calculate the difference in hours with `timediff` and `time_to_sec`
4. sum it up

`SELECT r.*, 
    GREATEST('05:30:00', timeFrom) AS startTime, LEAST('07:30:00', timeTo) AS endTime
    , time_to_sec(timediff(LEAST('07:30:00', timeTo), GREATEST('05:30:00', timeFrom))) / 3600
    , (time_to_sec(timediff(LEAST('07:30:00', timeTo), GREATEST('05:30:00', timeFrom))) / 3600) * cost
    FROM`roomcost`r
    WHERE WEEKDAY('2017-03-23') BETWEEN dayFrom AND dayTo 
    AND (timeFrom <= '05:30:00' OR timeTo >= '07:30:00')`

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more. The column "cost" means cost per hour. Could you help me get the exactly amount of range time from timeFrom to timeTo ?

Comment: Then, the input time range is between 2 scale of cost in same day.

Comment: SUM((time_to_sec(timediff(LEAST('07:30:00', timeTo), GREATEST('05:30:00', timeFrom))) / 3600) * cost) 
is used for cost per hour * booked hours

Comment: use my first SUM ... query.
the last one is just for testing purpose, so you can easily see what's going on.
there is one exception: you can't have overlapping time ranges in cost table

Comment: Thanks, I think my case is quite complicated with a simple query, so I created an php function and could get expected cost.